# How can I find the row in which error occurred while doing select with convert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm selecting data from a table. The select statement converts time to seconds. But it seems there are invalid time values in the table and it's causing the select statement to break.
Below is the statement:

```
select (DATEPART(hh, duration) * 60 * 60) + 
       (DATEPART(mi, duration) * 60) + 
       DATEPART(ss, duration) as TimeInSeconds
```

**Error I get is :**

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

**My Question:**
   Is there a way to know in which row the error occurred? 
Is there any feature in sql server like IsDate() which can validate time?

Comment: It actually never occurred to me that there might be a *right* way to do this. But I always just do `SELECT TOP n` and adjust `n` until I find it. It's tedious, but it works.

Comment: Are you storing it as a string?  If it's a datetime field, I don't see how `DATEPART` can fail.  [ISDATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) will check for valid date, time, or datetime.

Comment: Unfortunately Yes. Time is stored as string and I'm trying to get all the seconds value from it.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I tried it that way but data is just too big - around 30 million. I try to get the next record from the last row it selects before it errors but that doesn't seem to work. It comes in random order.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? If you wish to see all data please comment the WHERE clause

**Sample Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END

CREATE TABLE #TEMP(TableID VARCHAR(20),
                Duration VARCHAR(100),
                FaultDescription VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #TEMP
VALUES
('1', '2014-08-01 09:38:26.680', 'Correct'),
('2', '2014-80-01 09:38:26.680', 'Wrong Month'),
('3', '2014-08-100 09:38:26.680', 'Wrong Dtae'),
('4', '2014-08-01 09:38:90.680', 'Wrong Time'),
('5', '2014-08-01 09:38:680', 'Wrong time format'),
('6', '2014-08-02 09:08:26.680', 'Correct'),
('7', '2014-08-03 09:39:26.680', 'Correct');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT TableID,CASE 
          WHEN ISDATE(duration)=1 
             THEN (DATEPART(hh, duration) * 60 * 60) + 
                 (DATEPART(mi, duration) * 60) + 
                  DATEPART(ss, duration) 
      ELSE NULL
       END as TimeInSeconds,Duration,FaultDescription
FROM #TEMP
WHERE ISDATE(duration)=1
```

**Cleanup Script:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

To identify the rows having error directly you can use

```
WITH "cte"
AS
(
    SELECT 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "TableID" )
        , valid = isdate("Duration")
        , *
    FROM
        #Temp
)
SELECT
    rn
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    valid = 0
```

based on the test data provided by @Gouri Shankar Aechoor

Comment: Very close but I tested the data and found
    select isdate('08:26')  = 1 
is different to
    toselect isdate('39:26') = 0 ?
Strange, isn't it?

Comment: Looks like ISDATE expects the parameter to be time as in the time in digital watch not as in stopwatch? It treats 11:59 as 59 past 11 and not 11 minutes and 59 seconds - makes sense